# Plotting two curves with different x-datapoints in the same figure (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have two curves with different x-datapoints shown in the same plot:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Date']= ['2014-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2016-12-31', '2017-12-31']
df1['Value'] = [22, 44, 11, 55]
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Date']= ['2015-03-31', '2015-07-31', '2015-8-31', '2015-12-31']
df2['Value'] = [34, 39, 31, 27]

ax1 = df1.plot(x='Date', marker='o')
df2.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o')
```

In the above code the 2nd curve (df2-data) uses the x-datapoints of the df1-data, not it's own.

I can make it work by manipulating the data (e.g. add the missing Dates in df1 and df2 with NaN accordingly), but I would like to know if there is something like a simple setting directly in the df.plot()-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: I did convert those dates to datetimes using df['Date'] =
>   pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

One way to do this is to use `pd.concat` then use pandas plot:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['df1','df2'])\
  .set_index('Date', append=True)\
  .unstack(0)['Value']\
  .reset_index(0, drop=True)\
  .fillna(0).plot(marker='o')
```

[image]

More like a scatter plot:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['df1','df2'])\
   .set_index('Date', append=True)\
   .unstack(0)['Value']\
   .reset_index(0, drop=True)\
   .plot(marker='o',linestyle='none')
```

[image]